# How to determine the default font used by Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

I have created a list in SharePoint. Which more people can use to put data in. When I type something in the list SharePoint uses a certain font. But when I copy text from for example Word to my SharePoint list. The font is used which was used in Word.

I have 2 questions:

1. How can I determine the font that SharePoint uses as default?
2. And how to change the font of text in the list that has copied/paste from another application for example Word?

Greetings, 
Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for determining, what font is used, you can always use the Dev-Tools of the Webbrowser (Shortcut: `F12`). See my steps in the following picture (Google Chrome Webbrowser):

[image]

You can always use an in-between-step and copy your Word-Text to a text file (for example Notepad) and copy it from there again. That should remove the style of the origin and take the style of the target.